# Python: how to catch os.chdir FileNotFoundError execption

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code below: (am using python 3.6.4)

```
def recursedir(dirname, filename):
        os.chdir(dirname)
        try:
                # print('Searching in ' + os.getcwd())
                for root, subdir, files in os.walk('.'):
                        for fname in files:
                                if fnmatch.fnmatch(fname, filename):
                                        name = os.path.join(root, fname)
                                        name = re.sub(r"\.\\","", name)
                                        return name
        except FileNotFoundError:
                print(dirname + ' does NOT exist. SKIPPED')
        return None
```

But it seems that the "except FileNotFoundError" does not catch the error and I still get this error message:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
>   specified: 'e:\workspace\Share'

The e:\workspace\Share indeed does not exist, but I just want to print out a message saying "This directory does NOT exist" and continue on.

Comment: The `os.chdir(dirname)` needs to be inside the `try:` block.

Comment: @StephenRauch: That said, "handling" the caller passing a non-existent directory by `print`ing and returning `None` is hardly a useful behavior. The OP needs to rethink any design that takes them back to C's return values as error flags design.